# Is there a way to run a for loop as a go routine without putting it in a separate func

Tags: for-loop, go, goroutine

Let's say I want to set a for loop running but don't want to block the execution, obviously I can put the for loop in a function `f` and call `go f` and continue with my life,
but I was curious if there is a way to call `go for` directly, something like:

```
fmt.Println("We are doing something")
//line below is my question
go for i := 1; i < 10; i ++ {
    fmt.Println("stuff running in background")
} 
// life goes on
fmt.Println("c'est la vie")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to run each loop in the background, nest the goroutine in the loop and use the `sync.WaitGroup` structure.

```
import "sync"

fmt.Println("We are doing something")

//line below is my question
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

// Ensure all routines finish before returning
defer wg.Wait()

for i := 1; i < 10; i ++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Println("stuff running in background")
    }()
}

// life goes on
fmt.Println("c'est la vie")
```

Answer (score 13):

The only way to do this is indeed by creating a function around it. In your example this is how you would do it.

```
fmt.Println("We are doing something")
//line below is my question
go func() {
    for i := 1; i < 10; i ++ {
        fmt.Println("stuff running in background")
    } 
}()
// life goes on
fmt.Println("c'est la vie")
```

Make note of the actual calling of the function at the end `}()`. As otherwise the compiler will complain to you.